# Azure pipeline trigger on tags and branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am getting quiet confused here with Azure DevOps build pipeline and GitHub.

In my GitHub I have the following branches:

- Master
- Develop

My idea and intent is to have a develop pipeline that triggers on each commit to `develop` branch and master needs to trigger only and exclusively on tags.

So in develop branch I updated my pipelines as follow:

Development pipeline

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
```

and my master pipeline:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  tags:
    include:
      - '*'
  paths:
    exclude:
      - /*
```

Everything works fine and if I push to develop the pipeline triggers, if I create a tag in master also he pipeline works. The problem is if I create and push a tag on develop branch, automatically my master pipeline start building as well.

I don't understand this bit here. Why creating and pushing (not merging) my tag in develop branch triggers the build in master?

What I am expecting from those pipeline is that any push to development branch should trigger development pipeline, and `only` tags created IN master triggers master pipeline.

Please if anyone can help me to solve and understand this I will be so grateful.

And please if there is any question don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you once again

Comment: Did you get this to work on only the tag? I'm also looking for a solution which triggers on pushing the tag and not the branch itself.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers

> If you specify tags in combination with branch filters, the trigger
> will fire if either the branch filter is satisfied or the tag filter
> is satisfied. For example, if a pushed tag satisfies the branch
> filter, the pipeline triggers even if the tag is excluded by the tag
> filter, because the push satisfied the branch filter.

I suppose the best way to fix it is to have different naming conventions for tags for develop and for master and then update it accordingly in Yaml.

You can also tag your master commits which you want to deploy with 2 tags, for example your current tag "v.123" and new tag "master_to_be_deployed" and then in tags include section set include only for "master_to_be_deployed" instead of "*" wildcard.

You can also try to update branches section in master pipeline with exclude section, **I am almost sure it will not work acording to documentation**

```
  branches:
    include:
      - master
    exclude:
      - develop
```